# sql filter table data mismatch

Tags: sql, mysql

Here my sql code
`` SELECT * FROM `tblpatient` WHERE consent is NULL OR application is NULL AND PatientStatus = 'On Process' ``

I filter some data from sql table. **application** or **concent** anyone column is null and should be must **PatientStatus** column is equal to *On Process* only. But these two row is different value is displayed.

Where is the error?

Herewith Screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LtWH.png)